# How can i use list library for point an array?

Tags: c++, list

I want to point  array (created for each link) for each link. Can i do that with list library . third line is correct or not?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

class A{
 list<int> b;
 list<b> *c;// for use every link point a created array    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a little unclear and you can point to a array(as you call it) for each list by

```
list<list<int>> listOfList;
```

or more precisely you can point to an array for each link by

```
list<int *> listOfArray;
```

and your third line is not correct.

Comment: list<"classname"> b; // is this become correct? is the become i have list and its name is "classname" (classname=A)

Comment: If your "classname" is an actual type then list<classname> is valid. If your "classname" is an identifier then this is invalid.

Comment: as in the above code list<int> and int * are types so they are valid. But in your code b is an identifier so it's  in valid.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you use iterators to point into lists:

```
list<int>::iterator c;
```

You can initalize the iterator with

```
c = b.begin();
```

Comment: list<b> *c; , can i implement c like this line. is this correct?

Comment: Also would be worth mentioning that iterators shouln't be stored as members, but only used in iterations.

Comment: emre: no, your line is not correct.

Comment: @emreboyraz As said, it should be an iterator.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: there might actually be use cases of storing an iterator that points into the middle of a list, e.g. when you want to advance it on subsequent calls to some method.